# Is Asynchronous NSURLconnection in anyway helpful for real time update or sending constant request to the server in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsurl

I'm very much new to objective C. I have a case where I need to send request to the server URL at regular intervals. I made a asynchronous URL connection and used a NSTimer function to call the viewWillAppear function.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"myurl/test.csv"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];

       NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

       if(connection){
          label.text = @"connecting...";
        }else{
         //
        }


    }

 -(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
     [self viewWillAppear:TRUE];
      response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(response);
      }
```

I used the following NSTimer method to call the viewWillAppear method.

```
- (void)checkURLRequest
    {
     [self setProgressTimer:[NSTimer
                        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0f / 30.0f) 
                        target:self 
                        selector:@selector(viewWillAppear:) 
                        userInfo:self 
                        repeats:TRUE]];
    }

   - (void)setProgressTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
    {
    [_progressTimer invalidate];
     _progressTimer = theTimer;
    }
```

Is my approach even correct? Because when i updated the file 'test.csv' on the server, it can't do a live update as and when the file changes its still logging the old values in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move all the URL connection stuff outside the VC and into a custom class that does this using blocks.  This would allow you to use this in other classes and is better OO programming.  I can send you an example I use with image loading if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `viewWillAppear:` on your own, especially since it needs to call `[super viewWillAppear:]` which does things you don't know about. I can tell you from experience that calling these view controller methods yourself can lead to strange bugs that are very hard to debug.

So move your URL connection handling code into a separate method that you call with your timer and that you can also call in your `viewWillAppear:`, if you need to.

Comment: It depends, but generally you want to keep stuff *out* of the app delegate, or else it becomes one huge class that does everything. You generally want to keep things together.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right approach, in fact you should never call those viewcontroller callback methods such as viewWillAppear. I am not exactly sure on what code is being executed on the viewWillAppear, but the correct way to do this, would be to move that code to another method and call that method instead.